# js/jQuery: Stop event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener, handler

I have multiple DOM elememts. When each one becomes visible within the window then I fire an animation on that element.

Each element registers the window scroll event to the same event handler, passing this handler the element's ID and an event-specific callback function for the animation.

This single event handler tests if the element is on screen and if so fires the callback.

But ... it still listens for the window scroll event even after firing the callback. How can I turn off the scroll listener? jQuery "off" didn't work.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    sharedFunctionsModuleName.initialAnimationWhenChartBottomVisible({
        chartID: chartID,
        callbackFunction: thisWebpageModuleName.animationFunctionName
    });
});
```

Comment: How did you try `off`, `$(window).off('scroll');`

Comment: Hi Tushar, yes I tried that however this stops the listener for all elements. What I want to do is register a window scroll event for each dom element, then stop that element specific listener after the event handler has fired once.

Comment: I guess it's not a big deal for the scroll listener/listeners to keep listening. It just seems as if I want to stop the listening when it's no longer needed. 1 event, 1 handler, multiple elements.

Comment: Use a namespaced event, like `scroll.namespace`. You can then turn off all events associated with the namespace, or the scroll event for that particular namespace.

Comment: Terry, awesome! Thanks. jQuery event namespacing to the rescue. I found this online for those interested: https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

EventTarget.removeEventListener()?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

just use the one event instead of on

```
$(window).one('scroll', function () {
    sharedFunctionsModuleName.initialAnimationWhenChartBottomVisible({
        chartID: chartID,
        callbackFunction: thisWebpageModuleName.animationFunctionName
    });
});
```

this automatically unbinds after the first time its fired

The documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)